# trigger event from an AsyncCallback in c#

Tags: c#, events, controls, tcplistener, asynccallback

My question involves events and where I am triggering the events in my class. This class wraps my TCP functionality and I am using TcpListener to achieve this. I realize some TCP stuff may be missing from the following example but I want to make things as simple as possible:

**c# 2.0 sample**

```
class MyTcpClass
{
   public delegate void ClientConnectHandler(Socket client, int clientNum);

   public event ClientConnectHandler ClientConnect;

   private Socket wellKnownSocket;
   private Socket[] clientSockets = new Socket[MAX_CLIENTS];
   private int numConnected = 0;

   private void OnClientConnect(Socket client, int clientNum)
   {
      if (ClientConnect != null)
         ClientConnect(client, clientNum);
   }

   public void StartListening()
   {
      //initialize wellKnownSocket
      //...
      wellKnownSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(internal_clientConnect);
   }

   public void internal_clientConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
      //Add client socket to clientSocket[numConnected]
      //numConnected++;
      //...
      wellKnownSocket.EndAccept(ar);

      OnClientConnect(clientSocket[numConnected], numConnected);          
      //error: event happens on different thread!!
   }
}

class MainForm
{
   void Button_click()
   {
      MyTcpClass mtc = new MyTcpClass();
      mtc.ClientConnect += mtc_ClientConnected;
   }

   void mtc_clientConnected(Socket client, int clientNum)
   {
      ActivityListBox.Items.Add("Client #" + clientNum.ToString() + " connected.");
      //exception: cannot modify control on seperate thread
   }
}
```

I guess my question is, without breaking this pattern too much, what makes more sense? Also, if anyone has a better more elegant solution they are welcome.

**Theory**

```
class MainForm
{
   public MainForm()
   {
      MyTcpClass mtc = new MyTcpClass();
      MyTcpClass2 mtc2 = new MyTcpClass2(this);  
      //this version holds a Form handle to invoke the event

      mtc.ClientConnect += mtc_uglyClientConnect;
      mtc2.ClientConnect += mtc2_smartClientConnect;
   }

   //This event is being called in the AsyncCallback of MyTcpClass
   //the main form handles invoking the control, I want to avoid this
   void mtc_uglyClientConnect(Socket s, int n)
   {
      if (mycontrol.InvokeRequired)
      {
         //call begininvoke to update mycontrol
      }
      else
      {
         mycontrol.text = "Client " + n.ToString() + " connected.";
      }
   }

   //This is slightly cleaner, as it is triggered in MyTcpClass2 by using its
   //passed in Form handle's BeginInvoke to trigger the event on its own thread.
   //However, I also want to avoid this because referencing a form in a seperate class
   //while having it (the main form) observe events in the class as well seems... bad
   void mtc2_smartClientConnect(Socket s, int n)
   {
      mycontrol.text = "Client " + n.ToString() + " connected.";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you did not post the code for `MyTcpClass2`, I'm pretty sure I see what you're getting at.

No, I wouldn't do it the second way.  Because, for example, if anything else ever needs to bind to that event at the same time, you are going to force it to run on another thread.

In short, the method that receives the event should be responsible for running whatever code it needs to on whatever thread it needs to.  The mechanism that raises the event should be completely oblivious to any sort of weird threading stuff that the receiver requires.  Aside from complicating the multiple-event-binding scenario, it moves the logic of cross-thread invocation into a class where it doesn't belong.  The `MyTcpClass` class should be focused on handling TCP client/server matters, not mucking around with Winforms threads.

Comment: So you suggest the first example, where i access any winform control stuff in the event handler in MainForm using invocation? I realize MyTcpClass should be oblivious to what thread it is on, but MyTcpClass "Has An" asynchronous callback relationship with client connect. I would prefer to trigger the event in the thread (oblivious to which thread albeit) that MyTcpClass was created in. I see your point and agree with it, however Microsoft itself models a similar event with its "backgroundworker" with its progresschanged event.

Comment: @Tom: The problem is that this threading model is pretty specific to Winforms -- you may not even be able to invoke the event handler on the thread the class was created on!  (What if the thread terminated?)